# Multiple Signature Pad is not working after another field signed Bootstrap Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I use [szimek/signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) in my project, and have this implemented in show.blade.php:

```
<tr class="text-center">
        <td colspan="2" class="">
            {{-- Form with signature field here, unique for first_sign --}}
            @if ($first != null )
                <label for="firstSign">Pengganti Pertama:</label>
                <br>
                <img src="{{ asset('/storage/archive/signature/'.$first) }}" id="firstSign" alt="First Signature"/>
            @else
                <form id="firstSignatureForm" action="{{ route('backsite.paidLeave.sign.first') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="first-signature-pad">
                            <div class="signature-pad-header">
                                <label for="first-sign">Tanda Tangan:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="signature-pad-body">
                                <canvas id="first-sign" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;" class="first-sign border border-2 rounded"></canvas>
                            </div>
                            <div class="signature-pad-footer">
                                <button type="button" id="first-clear" class="first-clear btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
                                <button type="button" id="first-save" class="first-save btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="save" data-form="firstSignatureForm">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{ $paid_leave_transaction->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="first_sign" id="first_sign">
                </form>
            @endif
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            {{-- Another form with signature field here, unique for second_sign --}}
            @if ($second != null )
                <label for="secondSign">Pengganti Kedua:</label>
                <br>
                <img src="{{ asset('/storage/archive/signature/'.$second) }}" id="secondSign" alt="Second Signature"/>
            @else
                <form id="secondSignatureForm" action="{{ route('backsite.paidLeave.sign.second') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="second-signature-pad">
                            <div class="signature-pad-header">
                                <label for="second-sign">Pengganti Kedua:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="signature-pad-body">
                                <canvas id="second-sign" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;" class="second-sign border border-2 rounded"></canvas>
                            </div>
                            <div class="signature-pad-footer">
                                <button type="button" id="second-clear" class="second-clear btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
                                <button type="button" id="second-save" class="second-save btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="save" data-form="secondSignatureForm">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{ $paid_leave_transaction->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="second_sign" id="second_sign">
                </form>
            @endif
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            {{-- Another form with signature field here, unique for spv_sign --}}
            @if ($spv != null )
                <label for="spvSign">SPV:</label>
                <br>
                <img src="{{ asset('/storage/archive/signature/'.$spv) }}" id="spvSign" alt="SPV Signature"/>
            @else
                <form id="spvSignatureForm" action="{{ route('backsite.paidLeave.sign.spv') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="spv-signature-pad">
                            <div class="signature-pad-header">
                                <label for="spv-sign">SPV:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="signature-pad-body">
                                <canvas id="spv-sign" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;" class="border border-2 rounded"></canvas>
                            </div>
                            <div class="signature-pad-footer">
                                <button type="button" id="spv-clear" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
                                <button type="button" id="spv-save" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="save" data-form="spvSignatureForm">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{ $paid_leave_transaction->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="spv_sign" id="spv_sign">
                </form>
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
```

script:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // First
        const firstSignaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.querySelector("#first-sign"));
        const firstClearButton = document.querySelector("#first-clear");
        const firstSaveButton = document.querySelector("#first-save");
        // Event listener for the "Clear" button
        firstClearButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            firstSignaturePad.clear(); // Clears the canvas
        });

        // Event listener for the "Save" button
        firstSaveButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            // Convert the signature to a data URL
            const signatureDataURL = firstSignaturePad.toDataURL();

            // Set the data URL as the value of a hidden input field
            document.querySelector("#first_sign").value = signatureDataURL;

            // Submit the form
            // Note: Make sure the form has an ID attribute for this to work
            document.getElementById("firstSignatureForm").submit();
        });

        // Second
        const secondSignaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.querySelector("#second-sign"));
        const secondClearButton = document.querySelector("#second-clear");
        const secondSaveButton = document.querySelector("#second-save");
        // Event listener for the "Clear" button
        secondClearButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            secondSignaturePad.clear(); // Clears the canvas
            console.log('clears clicked');

        });

        // Event listener for the "Save" button
        secondSaveButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            // Convert the signature to a data URL
            const signatureDataURL = secondSignaturePad.toDataURL();

            // Set the data URL as the value of a hidden input field
            document.querySelector("#second_sign").value = signatureDataURL;

            // Submit the form
            // Note: Make sure the form has an ID attribute for this to work
            document.getElementById("secondSignatureForm").submit();
        });
        
        // SPV
        const spvSignaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.querySelector("#spv-sign"));
        const spvClearButton = document.querySelector("#spv-clear");
        const spvSaveButton = document.querySelector("#spv-save");
        // Event listener for the "Clear" button
        spvClearButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            spvSignaturePad.clear(); // Clears the canvas
            console.log('clears clicked');

        });

        // Event listener for the "Save" button
        spvSaveButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            // Convert the signature to a data URL
            const signatureDataURL = spvSignaturePad.toDataURL();

            // Set the data URL as the value of a hidden input field
            document.querySelector("#spv_sign").value = signatureDataURL;

            // Submit the form
            // Note: Make sure the form has an ID attribute for this to work
            document.getElementById("spvSignatureForm").submit();
        });
    });
```

The problem is, all of these signature works normally, when one of those not have been submitted. The problem appear when the first signature is submitted and showing as the image.

The others is not yet drawn and submitted. Yet, those canvas is not  yet declared. I figure it out when I check the html, its not in there. So basically, another canvas is not yet initalized, and rest of js is not compiled

How could this be happen? Im not expert in js, so pardon me if there's something that could be wrong

I have tried to add this:

```
console.log('clears clicked');
```

in each click function, but its not shows up on console

Also, have tried changing any

```
querySelector('#');
```

into

```
getElementsById('');
```

None of those got works

Comment: what happens if you comment first and spv and just use second? would the issue still remain?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth Sorry, I just updated my question. I just figured out some cause it wont works. Back to your question, yes it still remain. Even tough I only initialized the spv field. 

I confused, the canvas works normally, when there is no img, so its fine with the else condition is true. However, its not when the first if (displaying img) is true

Comment: `const firstClearButton = document.querySelector("#first-clear");` - this will not find any element, when you have already output an image for the first signature element - because in that case, you are not even _creating_ the form, that would contain this button. So trying to call `firstClearButton.addEventListener(...)` should give you a JavaScript error then.

Comment: @CBroe Ohh I see, so I should make another condition to make it initialize another field?

Comment: If you already have an image - do you then need the signature pad for that same value _again_? If not, don't output the JS code for that part then, either. And if so - if you want to give the user a way to replace the already existing signature again - then output the image _and_ the canvas element, and make the latter invisible first.

Comment: @CBroe yes I need. Because it should accommodate multiple user with different level. The further to the right, the higher the user level. That's why I initialize multiple canvas